# Factoring an exact square with respect to orthogonal factorization

Tags: category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$It has been surprisingly difficult to prove the following fact about orthogonal factorization.

Let $\cal C$ be a category with finite limits and colimits, and with a functorial, orthogonal factorization $(\cal E,M)$. Consider a square
$$\begin{CD}
A @>>> B \\ 
@VVV @VVV\\
C @>>> D
\end{CD}$$ which is at the same time a pullback and a pushout. Now, factor each side with respect to $(\cal E,M)$:
$$\begin{CD}
A @>e>> . @>m>> B \\ 
@VeVV @. @VVeV\\
. @.@. .\\
@VmVV @. @VVmV\\
C @>>e> . @>>m> D
\end{CD}$$
Push out the $e$'s in the top left corner, and pullback the $m$'s in the bottom right corner. Do these two squares glue? In other words, do you get a diagram like
$$\begin{CD}
A @>e>> . @>m>> B \\ 
@VeVV @VVV @VVeV\\
. @>>> ? @>>> .\\
@VmVV @VVV @VVmV\\
C @>>e> . @>>m> D
\end{CD}$$ for a unique object in the center, which is the factoring object of the $(\cal E,M)$-factorization of the common diagonal of the square (and of course, the top-right square commutes, and the bottom-left as well)?

I get a [very complicated diagram](https://i.postimg.cc/NMK3JTLh/image-2024-03-27-133345461.png) if I try to prove it bluntly. I don't think it's a difficult problem, and I would say it's just a matter of gluing together functorial factorization diagrams... but I can't see how.

Comment: By "glue", do you mean that the canonical morphism from the pushout to the pullback is an iso?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $E$ and $M$ are composition-closed classes containing isomorphisms, and any two factorizations of a morphism as $e\circ m$ for $e\in E$ and $m\in M$ are isomorphic.

Consider a factorizations of the morphisms in a commutative square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A@>e_1>>X_1@>m_1>>B\newline
@Ve_2VV@.@Ve_3VV\newline
X_2@.@.X_3\newline
@Vm_2VV@.@VVm_3V\newline
C@>>e_4>X_4@>>m_4>D
\end{CD}$$

The inclusion of a morphism $X_1\to X_4$ with a factorization $e\circ m\colon X_1\to Y\to X_4$ makes the diagram commute only if $(m_4\circ m)\circ(e\circ e_1)\colon A\to Y\to D$ is a factorization of the diagonal.

If the inclusion of a morphism $X_2\to X_3$ with factorization $m'\circ e'\colon X_2\to Z\to X_3$ also makes the diagram commute, then $(m_3\circ m')\circ (e'\circ e_2)$ is another factorization of the diagonal.

There is then an isomorphism $i\colon Y\cong Z$ with inverse $j\colon Z\cong Y$ such that $m_3\circ m'\circ i=m_4\circ m$ and $j\circ e'\circ e_2=e\circ e_1$. It follows that the factorization $(m'\circ i)\circ(j\circ e')\colon X_2\to Y\to X_4$ is compatible with $m\circ e\colon X_1\to Y\to X_4$ in the sense that including their factors makes the diagram commute.

By definition $(E,M)$ is a functorial factorization system only if every morphism has a factorization and in any commutative square as above there exists morphisms $X_2\to X_4$ and $X_1\to X_3$ whose inclusion makes the diagram commute. It follows that those morphisms have compatabile factorizations whose inclusion also makes the diagram commute.